# Remove punctuation at beginning and end of a string

Tags: c

I have a string and I want to remove all the punctuation from the beginning and the end of it only, but not the middle.

I have wrote a code to remove the punctuation from the first and last character of a string only, which is clearly very inefficient and useless if a string has 2 or more punctuations at the end.

Here is an example:

```
{ Hello ""I am:: a Str-ing!! }
```

Desired output

```
{ Hello I am a Str-ing }
```

Are there any functions that I could use? Thanks.

This is what I've done so far. I'm actually editing the string in a linked-list

```
if(ispunct(removeend->string[(strlen(removeend->string))-1]) != 0) { 
    removeend->string[(strlen(removeend->string))-1] = '\0'; 
} 
else {}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to strip punctuation from both ends of each *word* in a given string?

Comment: So you actually want to remove punctuation from the beginning and end of words in a string?

Comment: Wooble: post edited.
cha0site, EricSchaefer: Yes, beginning and end of each word in the string. But not the middle.

Comment: @Lim: Wait, so you already have each word as a seperate string in a linked list?

Comment: @Wooble: Yes. all separated. one word for each node. But I saved the whole thing including punctuation as a string. Just couldn't figure out how to remove those.

Comment: What about other characters, such as digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *rm_punct(char *str) {
  char *h = str;
  char *t = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while (ispunct(*p)) p++;
  while (ispunct(*t) && p < t) { *t = 0; t--; }
  /* also if you want to preserve the original address */
  { int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= t - p + 1; i++) {
      str[i] = p[i];
  } p = str; } /* --- */

  return p;
}
```

Comment: My next question was gonna be about pointers shifting too but this suddenly appeared and solved my question. Thank you.

Comment: This won't catch the two double quotes before 'I' in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the string, use isalpha() to check each character, write the characters which pass into a new string.

Comment: isalpha() will result in the whole string becoming alphabets, was hoping to remove the punctuation at the beginning and end of string only.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the string, use `isalpha()` to check each character, after the first character that passes start writing into a new string.

Iterate over the new string backwards, replace all punctuation with `\0` until you find a character which isn't punctuation.

Comment: isalpha() will result in the whole string becoming alphabets, was hoping to remove the punctuation at the beginning and end of string only. Besides I thought \0 indicates end of string, I understand to replace \0 at the end and '' at the beginning, but how can I remain the punctuation in middle part?

Comment: @Lim: You misunderstood me. My solution has 2 passes: First, find the **first** non-punctuation character in the string. `isalpha()` is useful for that. Once you have that, copy everything into a new string. Now you have a string that has no punctuation in the beginning. Now you can remove the punctuation from the end by replacing all characters with `\0` until you hit a non-punctuation character (going backwards over the string).

Comment: It doesn't work because you have to `sscanf` or `strtok` the whole string and process separately each substring.

Comment: @A_nto2: He stated in the comments that he had each word in a separate string in a linked list.

Comment: @cha0site: Ok, I've just seen that. damn it...:) So your answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in a `while` iteration, call multiple times the `strtok` function to separate each single string by the character (white space). You could also use `sscanf` instead of `strtok`.

Then, for each string, you have to do a `for` cycle, but beginning from the end of the string up to the beginning.As soon as you encounter `!isalpha(current character)` put a `\0` in the current string position. You have eliminated the tail's punctuation chars.

Now,  do another `for` cycle on the same string. Now from `0` to `strlen(currentstring)`. While is `!isalpha(current character)` `continue`. If `isalpha` put the current character in in a `buffer` and all the remaining characters.  The `buffer` is the cleaned string. Copy it into the original string.

Repeat the above two steps for the others `strtok`'s outputs. End.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char* trim_ispunct(char* str){
    int i ;
    char* p;

    if(str == NULL || *str == '\0') return str;
    for(i=strlen(str)-1; ispunct(str[i]);--i)
        str[i]='\0';
    for(p=str;ispunct(*p);++p);

    return strcpy(str, p);
}

int main(){
    //test
    char str[][16] = { "Hello", "\"\"I", "am::", "a", "Str-ing!!" };
    int i, size = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
    for(i = 0;i<size;++i)
        printf("%s\n", trim_ispunct(str[i]));

    return 0;
}
/* result:
Hello
I
am
a
Str-ing
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Construct a tiny state machine. The cha2class() function divides the characters into equivalence classes. The state machine will always skip punctuation, except when it has alphanumeric characters on the left and the right; in that case it will be preserved. (that is the memmove() in state 3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IS_ALPHA 1
#define IS_WHITE 2
#define IS_PUNCT 3
int cha2class(int ch);
void scrutinize(char *str);

int cha2class(int ch)
{
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') return IS_ALPHA;
if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') return IS_ALPHA;
if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t') return IS_WHITE;
if (ch == EOF || ch == 0) return IS_WHITE;
return IS_PUNCT;
}

void scrutinize(char *str)
{
size_t pos,dst,start;
int typ, state ;

state = 0;
for (dst = pos = start=0; ; pos++) {
        typ = cha2class(str[pos]);
        switch(state) {
        case 0: /* BOF, white seen */
                if (typ==IS_WHITE) break;
                else if (typ==IS_ALPHA) { start =  pos; state =1; }
                else if (typ==IS_PUNCT) { start =  pos; state =2; continue;}
                break;
        case 1: /* inside a word */
                if (typ==IS_ALPHA) break;
                else if (typ==IS_WHITE) { state=0; }
                else if (typ==IS_PUNCT) { start =  pos; state =3;continue; }
                break;
        case 2: /* inside punctuation after whitespace: skip it */
                if (typ==IS_PUNCT) continue;
                else if (typ==IS_WHITE) { state=0; }
                else if (typ==IS_ALPHA)  {state=1; }
                break;
        case 3: /* inside punctuation after a word */
                if (typ==IS_PUNCT) continue;
                else if (typ==IS_WHITE) { state=0; }
                else if (typ==IS_ALPHA) {
                        memmove(str+dst, str+start, pos-start); dst += pos-start;
                        state =1; }
                break;
                }
        str[dst++] = str[pos];
        if (str[pos] == '\0') break;
        }
}
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
char test[] = ".This! is... ???a.string?" ;

scrutinize(test);

printf("Result=%s\n", test);

return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
char test[] = ".This! is... ???a.string?" ;

scrutinize(test);

printf("Result=%s\n", test);

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Result=This is a.string
```